# ReactJS test files issue 'cannot find module' because of webpack module resolver

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack-2, babeljs

i'm developing an application with react.js. My application is growing up. So i had little trouble with imports. For example i have a component named `foo` i'm using it in many places.

```
import foo from '../../components/foo';
import foo from '../components/foo';
import foo from '../../../components/foo';
```

As you can see its dirty, not good. So i searched to fix it and i found a solution with webpack. Also i read that title **(Configure Webpack’s modules resolution to avoid nested imports)** in this [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/organize-large-react-application/)

I added this code into my `webpack.config.js` file

```
modules: [
     'node_modules',
     path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
  ]
```

So my resolve object looks like this

```
export default {
resolve: {
  modules: [
     'node_modules',
     path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
  ],
  extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
},
...
```

After that i am able to use import my foo component in anywhere like this.

```
import foo from 'components/foo';
```

Everything is okay so far. But problem shows up in test files.

When i try to test `foo` component it says

> Cannot find module 'components/foo' from 'foo.js'

Example test file.

`foo.spec.js`

```
    import React from 'react';
    import foo from 'components/foo';

    describe('(Component) foo', () => {
       it('should render foo', () => {
         expect(true).toBe(true);
       });
    });
```

Here is the first problem. I can not import foo like this.

> Note: My test file is not in `src` folder it is in the `test` folder.

So i changed the path like this then it worked.

```
import foo from '../../../src/components/foo';
```

Tes passed everything is looks fine. But we still have the path problem in test files.
Lets try to import another component in `foo` component.

`foo.js`

```
import bar from 'components/admin/bar';
```

Here is the **second problem**. Test file FAILED error message is

> Cannot find module 'components/admin/bar' from 'foo.js'

I moved my test file in to my `foo.js` file. But didn't worked.

Here is my whole `webpack.config.js`

```js
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import path from 'path';
export default {
   resolve: {
      modules: [
         'node_modules',
         path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
      ],
      extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
   },
   devtool: 'inline-source-map', // more info:https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html#sourcemaps and https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
   entry: [
      // must be first entry to properly set public path
      './src/webpack-public-path',
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js') // Defining path seems necessary for this to work consistently on Windows machines.
   ],
   target: 'web', // necessary per https://webpack.github.io/docs/testing.html#compile-and-test
   output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
   },
   plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
         'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'), // Tells React to build in either dev or prod modes. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html (See bottom)
         __DEV__: true,
         //'API_URL': API_URL.dev
      }),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({     // Create HTML file that includes references to bundled CSS and JS.
         template: 'src/index.ejs',
         minify: {
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true
         },
         inject: true
      }),
      new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         minimize: false,
         debug: true,
         noInfo: true, // set to false to see a list of every file being bundled.
         options: {
            sassLoader: {
               includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'scss')]
            },
            context: '/',
            postcss: () => [autoprefixer],
         }
      })
   ],
   module: {
      rules: [
         {test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel-loader']},
         {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
         {
            test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
         },
         {test: /\.[ot]tf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
         {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
         {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'},
         {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'},
         {
            test: /(\.css|\.scss|\.sass)$/,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
         }
      ]
   }
};
```

How can i solve?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack is not used during test execution. Since you are using babel the `babel-plugin-module-resolver` https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver should solve the issue:

in your `.babelrc` file

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"]
    }]
  ]
}
```

A more cleaner approach would be to create an `alias` in your `.babelrc` file and then import from that alias, for instance:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        ["module-resolver", {
            "alias": {
                "@app": "./src"
            }
        }]
    ]
}
```

And in your file:
`import foo from '@app/components/foo'`

That way you have no naming conflicts and your paths are nice and short.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I installed the plugin.
`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver`

Then i updated my .babelrc file as said in documentation. After that first i tried to run the app before run the tests. But app failed. Modules can not find.

Comment: have you removed the webpack module resolver? they might interfere.

Comment: Yes i removed. Then i added this code in to .babelrc in to plugins object
`["module-resolver", 
               {"root": ["./src"]}
            ]`

Then i typed npm install then i started the app but  failed.
**ERROR in ./src/redux/store/configureStore.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'redux/reducers'**

And many other resolve errors.

Comment: By the way , my project structure is like this.

src > layout, provider, redux
test > layout, redux

Comment: Project structure : https://paste2.org/UaWG7Mw0
.babelrc : https://paste2.org/8MzgGGJF
webpack.config.js : https://paste2.org/UjJJ8DsW

Comment: pasting the imports of `/src/redux/store/configureStore.js` would be a great help. There are bound to be naming conflict if directory names and package names are the same (e.g. redux)

Comment: No i don't think so its about conflict directory names and package names. Because with the webpack resolve config it was working just fine.
Anyway here is the configureStore.js 
https://paste2.org/LZIbKfEn

Comment: if you import from `redux/reducers` there is no way telling which file to import. adding an alias to your babelrc would solve this: `["module-resolver", {
                "alias": {
                    "app": "./src"
                }
            }]` this way you now have to import from `app/redux/reducers` but you get rid of all the `../../../`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after i changed this jest object in package.json file.

```
"jest": {
  "moduleDirectories": [
     "node_modules",
     "src"
  ]
  ...
```